# Oracle: Limit results of a select statement to XXX number of rows for each record

Tags: sql, oracle, select, limit

I have a scenario where I want to pull up to the first 500 rows for each agent_ID on a table.
Example:

TABLE NAME: AGENT 
Schema: AGENT_ID, CUST_ID, CUST_F_NAME, CUST_L_NAME 
PK: CUST_ID

Scenario:

```
AGENT_ID 1234 has 800 results
AGENT_ID 4567 has 1000 results
AGENT_ID 1212 has 300 results
```

I would like my results to pull only up to 500 records for each AGENT_ID.  This table has hundreds of distinct AGENT_ID's.

I am having issues trying to write a SQL that will pull down this data and would like some help or suggestions.

Comment: You really named AGENT a table containing customers? Do you have a table containing agents? I mean 1 row per agent with agent_id primary key

Comment: That's not the real table name, just giving an example.  1 agent has multiple customers and on this table the customer has the agent_ID associated with it.  I want to be able to pull down a list of the customer for each agent, but not have the results exceed 500 for each agent.  There is a limitation on another system that creates a list from the results and that limits to 500 so I need to create another SQL to pull in rows 501 - 1000 as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use analytic function `row_number()` (or perhaps `rank()`) to do this:

```
select agent_id, cust_id, cust_f_name, cust_l_name
from
( select agent_id, cust_id, cust_f_name, cust_l_name
  ,      row_number() over (partition by agent_id order by whatever) as rn
  from   agent
)
where rn <= 500;
```

Change `whatever` to a list of columns that gets you the data you want (latest 500, oldest 500 or whatever).